# Cannot define a background property in mixin as "/" is misinterpreted as a calculation

Tags: scss-mixins

I have a series of buttons which use svg icons and I'm trying to convert the definition of each one using a mixin that takes a name, x/y position and a size and create a background css rule.  The problem is that defining a background image with the shorthand `background` css rule includes setting a position and size using the format "xpos ypos / xsize ysize" and the mixin wrongly interprets the "/" character as part of a calculation.

Here is my scss prior to converting to a mixing (which works):

```
$icons: "/images/my-icons.svg";

.section-icon-home {
    background: url('#{$icons}#section-home') 50% 48% / 42% 42% no-repeat;
}
.section-icon-insights {
    background: url('#{$icons}#section-insights') 50% 46% / 42% 42% no-repeat;
}
.section-icon-notifications {
    background: url('#{$icons}#section-notifications') 50% 50% / 40% 40% no-repeat;
}
.section-icon-help {
    background: url('#{$icons}#section-help') 50% 49% / 39% 39% no-repeat;
}
```

Here is what I'm trying to use with a mixin:

```
$icons: "/images/my-icons.svg";

@mixin section-icon($name, $x, $y, $size) {
    .section-icon-#{$name} {
        background: url('#{$icons}#section-#{$name}') $x $y / $size $size no-repeat;
    }
}
@include section-icon('home', 50%, 50%, 42%);
@include section-icon('insights', 50%, 46%, 42%);
@include section-icon('notifications', 50%, 50%, 40%);
@include section-icon('help', 50%, 49%, 39%);
```

and this is the error I get:
[image]

```
Deprecation Warning: Using / for division outside of calc() is deprecated and will be removed in Dart Sass 2.0.0.

Recommendation: math.div($y, $size) or calc($y / $size)

More info and automated migrator: https://sass-lang.com/d/slash-div

    ╷
117 │         background: url('#{$icons}#section-#{$name}') $x $y / $size $size no-repeat;
    │                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^
    ╵
    ..\..\Source\Core\PlatformNET\theme\RS4\styles\_parts\_header_sectionicons.scss 117:52  section-icon()
    ..\..\Source\Core\PlatformNET\theme\RS4\styles\_parts\_header_sectionicons.scss 120:1   @import
    ..\..\Source\Core\PlatformNET\theme\RS4\styles\_parts\_header.scss 237:9                @import
    ..\..\Source\Core\PlatformNET\theme\Geldards\styles\theme.scss 7:9                      root stylesheet
```

Is there any syntaxical way to fix this without resorting to breaking the shorthand `background` rule into multiple longhand background rules?  Thanks.